# Una matriz no se muestra bien

Tags: matrices

Estoy calculando la matriz inversa de una matriz en la que usuario da los datos y se muestra bien, excepto por tres elementos que solo salen como igual a cero. Esta es la función que imprime la matriz, y para cualquier valor de elementos, hay tres valores que me dan cero.

```
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<=2; j++){
        inversa[i][j] = adj[j][i] / determinante;
        cout<<inversa[j][i]<<"      ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Estos son los resultados que me dan:

```
    Ingrese la matriz de 3*3 dimensiones:

Posicion [0][0]: 1
Posicion [0][1]: 2
Posicion [0][2]: 3
Posicion [1][0]: 5
Posicion [1][1]: 6
Posicion [1][2]: 4
Posicion [2][0]: 8
Posicion [2][1]: 9
Posicion [2][2]: 1

La matriz inversa es:
-2              0               0
-1.66667                -1.53333                0
-0.666667               -0.733333               -0.266667
```

Los valores de Posicion[0][1], Posicion[0][2] y Posicion[1][2] dan cero.

Comment: cuanto vale determinante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que no es problema...
Tu código funciona bien, hace lo que tiene que hacer, solo lo muestra mal.
El error está en las dos siguientes lineas:

```
inversa[i][j] = adj[ j ][ i ] / determinante;
cout<<inversa[ j ][ i ]<<"      ";
```

Así como están, sacas por consola posiciones de la matriz, que aún no han sido instanciadas (muestran el valor default), deberías usar:

```
inversa[i][j] = adj[ j ][ i ] / determinante;
cout<<inversa[ i ][ j ]<<"      ";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me ayudo mucho tu respuesta

Comment: Un placer maestro!.

Answer (score 0):

El problema con tu código está en la forma en que estás calculando la matriz inversa y en cómo la estás imprimiendo. La matriz inversa de una matriz no necesariamente tendrá ceros en ciertas posiciones específicas, a menos que la matriz original tenga ciertas propiedades especiales.

Para calcular correctamente la matriz inversa, debes seguir una serie de pasos:

Calcular la matriz adjunta (adjunta) de la matriz original.
Calcular el determinante (determinante) de la matriz original.
Calcular la matriz inversa (inversa) dividiendo cada elemento de la matriz
adjunta por el determinante.

Aquí hay una función que puedes utilizar para calcular la matriz inversa correctamente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N = 3; // Tamaño de la matriz (3x3 en este caso)

// Función para calcular la matriz inversa
void calcularInversa(float matriz[N][N]) {
    float adjunta[N][N];
    float determinante = 0;

    // Cálculo del determinante (puedes implementar una función para ello)
    // El determinante no debe ser igual a cero para que la matriz tenga inversa.

    // Cálculo de la matriz adjunta
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            // Código para calcular la adjunta[i][j]
        }
    }

    // Cálculo de la matriz inversa
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = adjunta[i][j] / determinante;
        }
    }
}

// Función para imprimir la matriz
void imprimirMatriz(float matriz[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << matriz[i][j] << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    float matriz[N][N];

    cout << "Ingrese la matriz de " << N << "*" << N << " dimensiones:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << "Posicion [" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    calcularInversa(matriz);

    cout << "La matriz inversa es:" << endl;
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);

    return 0;
}
```

Recuerda que para obtener la matriz inversa correctamente, el determinante de la matriz original debe ser diferente de cero. Si el determinante es cero, significa que la matriz no tiene inversa, y es probable que eso esté causando los ceros que observas en ciertas posiciones de la matriz inversa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta